# Object serializing via RTTI doesn't work anymore

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have 2 years old project which I am rebooting back to life. I have debug window which shows different information, and one part of them is that it serializes various `google protobuf` objects and shows them.

Here is how typical `protobuf` class looks like:

```
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// Source: message.proto
unit Poker.Protobufs.Objects.PingParams;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  {$IFNDEF FPC} System.Generics.Collections {$ELSE} Contnrs {$ENDIF},
  pbOutput, Poker.Protobufs.Objects.Base, Poker.Protobufs.Reader, Poker.Types;

type
  TPB_PingParams = class(TProtobufBaseObject)
  private
    const
      kUptimeFieldNumber = 1;

    var
      FUptime: UInt32;
      FHasBits: UINT32;

    procedure set_has_Uptime;
    procedure clear_has_Uptime;
    procedure SetUptime(const AValue: UInt32);
  public
    constructor Create(const AFrom: TPB_PingParams; const ALightweight: Boolean = FALSE); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure LoadFromProtobufReader(const AProtobufReader: TProtobufReader; const ASize: Integer); override;
    procedure MergeFrom(const AFrom: TPB_PingParams);
    procedure Clear;
    function IsInitialized: Boolean; override;

    // required uint32 Uptime = 1;
    function has_Uptime: Boolean;
    procedure clear_Uptime;
    property Uptime: UInt32 read FUptime write SetUptime;
  end;

  TPB_PingParamsList = class(TObjectList<TPB_PingParams>)
    procedure Assign(const APB_PingParamsList: TList<TPB_PingParams>);
  end;

implementation

uses
  pbPublic;


constructor TPB_PingParams.Create(const AFrom: TPB_PingParams; const ALightweight: Boolean = FALSE);
begin
  inherited Create(ALightweight);
  MergeFrom(AFrom);
end;

destructor TPB_PingParams.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.LoadFromProtobufReader(const AProtobufReader: TProtobufReader; const ASize: Integer);
var
  tag, field_number, wire_type, endpos: Integer;
begin
  endpos := AProtobufReader.getPos + ASize;
  while (AProtobufReader.getPos < endpos) and
        (AProtobufReader.GetNext(tag, wire_type, field_number)) do
    case field_number of
      kUptimeFieldNumber: begin
        Assert(wire_type = WIRETYPE_VARINT);
        FUptime := AProtobufReader.readUInt32;
        set_has_Uptime;
      end;
    else
      AProtobufReader.skipField(tag);
    end;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.MergeFrom(const AFrom: TPB_PingParams);
begin
  if AFrom.has_Uptime then
    SetUptime(AFrom.Uptime);
end;

function TPB_PingParams.IsInitialized: Boolean;
begin
  if (FHasBits and $1) <> $1 then
    Exit(FALSE);
  Exit(TRUE);
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.clear_Uptime;
begin
  FUptime := 0;
  clear_has_Uptime;
end;

function TPB_PingParams.has_Uptime: Boolean;
begin
  result := (FHasBits and 1) > 0;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.set_has_Uptime;
begin
  FHasBits := FHasBits or 1;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.clear_has_Uptime;
begin
  FHasBits := FHasBits and not 1;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.SetUptime(const AValue: UInt32);
begin
  if not Lightweight then
    Assert(not has_Uptime);
  FUptime := AValue;
  if not Lightweight then
    ProtobufOutput.writeUInt32(kUptimeFieldNumber, AValue);
  set_has_Uptime;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParams.Clear;
begin
  if FHasBits = 0 then
    Exit;

  clear_Uptime;
end;

procedure TPB_PingParamsList.Assign(const APB_PingParamsList: TList<TPB_PingParams>);
var
  pbobj: TPB_PingParams;
begin
  Clear;
  for pbobj in APB_PingParamsList do
    Add(TPB_PingParams.Create(pbobj, TRUE));
end;

end.
```

And my serialization function:

```
function SerializeObject(const AObject: TObject): String;
var
  t: TRttiType;
  p: TRttiProperty;
  properties: TArray<TRttiProperty>;
  method: TRttiMethod;
begin
  result := '';
  if not Assigned(AObject) then
    Exit;

  t := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(AObject.ClassType);
  properties := t.GetProperties;
  for p in properties do
  begin
    method := t.GetMethod(Format('has_%s', [p.Name]));
    if (Assigned(method)) and
       (method.Invoke(AObject, []).AsBoolean) then
      result := result + Format('%s: %s; ', [p.Name, ValueToStr(p, p.GetValue(AObject))]);
  end;
end;
```

It is specifically designed to serialize fields that begin with `has_` in protobuf objects. Now, I didn't change anything in the code over last 2 years, and this was working before. But now it doesn't. Line `properties = t.GetProperties` returns empty array for my `protobuf` classes.

My guess is that I had some globally defined compiler directive which allowed me to serialize public methods in the class. But I cannot figure out which one.

If I put `{$M+}` in front of my `protobuf` classes, and move methods to `published`, it works (kinda). But this worked before just like it is shown in the sources, without any `{$M+}` directives or similar. So I'm curious what I miss.

Compiler is same as before, XE2.

Comment: See [RTTI directive (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/RTTI_directive_(Delphi)) for how to adjust RTTI visibility.

Comment: Yes, if I use that combined with `{$M+}` and `{$METHODINFO ON}`, it works, however I didn't have this at all in my project before, and it worked, under identical compiler.

Comment: Did you previously have `{$m+}` on the base class `TProtobufBaseObject`? RTTI generation is a heritable trait.

Comment: The `{$RTTI xxx}` directive is documented with local scope, but a bug made it extend its scope until XE6.

Comment: Bug report: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79943

Comment: The source code didn't change at all. Those two classes I linked above are the same as before. Same goes for `TProtobufBaseObject` class. Also, compiler is identical. It puzzles me why it doesn't work now, and it did before. So it means, something has to be different in the project, aside from these units.

Comment: As the report notices, just shuffling the order of units can change how rtti works.

Comment: Alright. So what I did is that I put `{$METHODINFO ON} {$TYPEINFO ON}` in `TProtobufBaseObject` class, and `{$RTTI INHERIT}` in every child `protobuf` class that inherits it, and moved their properties I want to enumerate to `published`. Hopefully this is the right way to fix things.

Comment: An include file is the perfect way to handle this.

Comment: And `{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPublic])}` is probably better than making all published.

Comment: Include file where? Afaik, include file is relevant for unit scope too, so I would have to include it in every unit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136193/discussion-between-marko-paunovic-and-lu-rd).

Comment: Clearly something changed. Use your revision control system to find out what that was.